# add SATA drive to poweredge beside current raid

Tags: dell-poweredge

I have a poweredge r415. There are 4 front-bays, 2 of which are occupied by 300gb SAS drives configured in a raid0 array.

I would like to add a SATA drive to the third bay so that I can perform backups to it; so it would not be part of the RAID array and would be seen as /dev/sdb or whatever by the OS.

I already have a drive and a caddy lying around and have installed it but cannot see it in the OS.

I assume this is because of the backplane and raid controller and am starting to think this isn't possible.

Is this possible? Do I need to enabled a specific 'sata port' in the bios?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The new drive should be configured within the RAID card for it to be seen by the OS. This operation can be done in many ways, however installing `Dell OpenManage Server Administrator` is probably an easy solution.

The configuration you should assign to a single disk is RAID 0.

Comment: Thanks! I created a live usb with OMSA but I don't see the sata drive under 'storage' in OMSA.  Trying to create a new virtual disk says there is no space available.

Comment: What do the status lights on the caddy say ?